# java 8 event listener/dispatcher using lambdas/method references - how to achieve certain things?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to write an event engine in Java using the newly added lambdas. I would very much like it if the following code would work:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        EventEngine.listen(EventType.THIS, self::thisEventCallback);
        EventEngine.listen(EventType.THAT, self::thatEventCallback);
        EventEngine.listen(EventType.OTHER, (other) -> other.doX());
    }

    private void thisEventCallback()
    {
        // do whatever here
    }

    private boolean thatEventCallback(SomeObject parameter)
    {
        return parameter.someCheckOrWhatever();
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, I would have to define a generic empty interface, for example, `public interface Listener {// nothing here}`, and extend it via various other interfaces for each event type so I can specify different parameters and return types where necassary.
Obviously, that would require casting the callbacks to the specific interface inside the EventEngine's trigger method(s), but I have no problem with that.

However, before that I need to find out how to reference these private methods I have defined to the `EventDispatcher.listen` method. `self::thisEventCallback` doesn't work. Is there even a way to do this in Java 8 or is it only possible in Scala?

If not, then what would you suggest as a replacement that does not involve creating a new object for every listener/callback?

Comment: In Java it is `this` not `self`. That’s all.

Comment: @Holger - damn it, I could swear I tried it and it didn't work before... Now I just have to figure out how to make it work simultaneously for methods and lambdas.

Comment: Note that you can even work without casting: instead of having an empty base `interface` and sub-`interface`s with one method, you can have a base `interface` declaring *all* methods and sub-`interface`s overriding all but one method with empty `default` methods.

Comment: @Holger - sounds good, I'll see what I can do with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    EventEngine.listen(EventType.THIS, this::thisEventCallback);
    EventEngine.listen(EventType.THAT, this::thatEventCallback);
    EventEngine.listen(EventType.OTHER, (other) -> other.doX());
```

So `this` instead of `self`.

And you need functional interfaces with *one* abstract method having the same signature as the callback.

```
public interface THISInterface {
    public void thisEventCallback();
}

public interface THATInterface {
    public boolean thatEventCallback(SomeObject parameter)
}

class EventEngine {
    public void listen(Type t, THISInterfcace thisCallback) {
        thisCallback.thisEventCallback();
    }
    public void listen(Type t, THATInterfcace thatCallback) {
        boolean ok = thatCallback.thatEventCallback();
    }
    ...
}
```

However there are already many [functional interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) predefined, which you should need to learn. For instance here, one would not need own interfaces.

```
class EventEngine {
    public void listen(Type t, Consumer<Void> thisCallback) {
        thisCallback.accept();
    }
    public void listen(Type t, Predicate<Void> thatCallback) {
        boolean ok = thatCallback.test();
    }
```

Whether the above is correct, I am not sure (at the moment deep in java 6 - sigh).

Comment: Yeah, the predefined interfaces are good, but they don't have a generic type, and I'm storing the callbacks in `EnumMap<EventType, Set<Listener>>` in EventEngine, where Listener is the common interface for all callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating sub-`interface`s adding new methods to a base `interface` you can define a conventional listener `interface` (like, say [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)) having multiple call-back methods and create sub-`interface`s overriding all but one method with empty `default` methods for the sole purpose of allowing lambda implementations of the remaining single `abstract` method. They replace what classes like `MouseAdapter` did for previous Java versions (when using anonymous inner classes):

```
interface AllPurposeListener {// the only one our engine uses internally
    void caseOne(int arg);
    void caseTwo(String arg);
}
interface CaseOneListener extends AllPurposeListener {
    @Override public default void caseTwo(String arg) {}
}
interface CaseTwoListener extends AllPurposeListener {
    @Override public default void caseOne(int arg){}
}

// Of course, I over-simplify the engine’s listener registry here
AllPurposeListener listener;
public void listen(AllPurposeListener l) {
    listener=l;
}
public void listen(CaseOneListener l) {
    listener=l;
}
public void listen(CaseTwoListener l) {
    listener=l;
}

private void foo(int i) { }
private void bar(String s) { }
void doRegistration() {
    listen(this::foo);// register for case one
    listen(this::bar);// register for case two
    listen(new AllPurposeListener() { // for all cases
        public void caseOne(int arg) {
        }
        public void caseTwo(String arg) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not make all the methods default in the AllPurposeListener and override only one of them in the child interfaces? P.S. I'd name it `GenericListener`.

Comment: That would work the same. I got used to do it this way because there are already plenty of listener interfaces (like the different AWT listener interfaces) without default methods. So for these interfaces, I don’t touch them (can’t change them) but create the sub-interfaces were feasible.